# Custom styles not working with deck.js

Tags: css, deck.js

I'm creating a presentation using deck.js, the problem that I'm having is that whenever I try to use custom styles eg to add border to tables or to use google code prettify, it has absolutely no effect.
The presentation can be found [here](https://github.com/nikhilbhardwaj/Intro-to-CLI/blob/master/presentation.html).

**Edit:**
I have the following snippet for displaying source code.

```
<code class="prettyprint">
chmod 000 filename
cat filename
</code>
```

How exactly is this affected by the CSS Specificity issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most deck styles are scoped under `.deck-container`. As in: `.deck-container pre { ... }`. Your custom styles probably do not have enough [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to override this. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: How can I deal with specificity when using google code prettify?

Comment: I'd either edit the deck CSS to remove the styles that conflict with prettify, or edit the prettify CSS to add .deck-container in front of each rule (easy if you're using Sass or LESS).